# Interpretation of lasso shrinkage

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca, lasso, ridge-regression

In the case of the ridge estimator, we can interpret the shrinkage induced by the ridge estimator to be at its most extreme when a predictor has low variance. High-variance predictors provide the most information/signal about our response, and low-variance ones contribute to "noise" which should be shrunk down - reminiscent of a continuous version of PCA here.

Is there a similar interpretation to the lasso? That is, how does lasso choose which covariates to shrink down and truncate and what does that imply about them? If a predictor is dropped by lasso, can we then suggest that that predictor was weak/low variance/irrelevant?

Comment: Where do you get your first paragraph from?  Do you mean variance or co-variance?

Comment: On your second paragraph, I suspect in a hand waving sense the dropped predictors had a higher "cost/benefit ratio" than retained predictors

Comment: normally, predictors are scaled to unit variance. So its more that shrinkage is most extreme in directions of low correlation between predictors.( so its 'averaging' over predictors).